# How to count rows between 2 non empty cells with their intermediary empty cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count each rows of empty cells between two non-empy cells and adding the upper non empty-cell count (or the lower non-empty cells count)  to the result when the empty cells/rows numbers are variable and irregular in this manner:

```
A1 Empty
A2 Non-empty
A3 Empty
A4 Empty
A5 Empty
A6 Empty
A7 Non-empty
```

(with A2 to A5 being irregular — could be any number of intermediary empty rows/cells — i.e. 10, 2, 30, 5, etc., and variable — could be located in any location within Column A)

The result should return as follow:

```
=IFS(

AND(A2="",A3=""),"",

AND(A2="",A3<>""),"",

AND(A2<>"",A3<>""),ROWS(A2),

AND(A2<>"",A3=""),ROWS(A2:UP TO NEXT NON-EMPTY ROW BENEATH (NOT COMPRISED (or minus the next non-empty row(-1)))
```

How do we program Google Sheets to count rows "UP TO NEXT NON-EMPTY ROW BENEATH (NOT COMPRISED (or minus the next ono empty row(-1)) when the emppty intermediary rows' count is variable/unknown for each occurence and irregular/can be any number of intremediary rows?

I have this data as example:

[image]

So far, I've come up with this partial solution:

```
=IFS(AND(A2="",A3=""),"", AND(A2="",A3<>""),"", AND(A2<>"",A3<>""),ROWS(A2), AND(A2<>"",A3=""),ROWS(A2:UP TO NEXT NON-EMPTY ROW BENEATH (NOT COMPRISED (or minus the next non-empty row(-1)))))
```

[image]

The expected result should return as follows:

[image]

The Sheet copy:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eLXdFINKVtS5Fxon8mIQDmBUTZokyY_Fb6tfWJRDOVI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to say that I find this very confusing, even after looking at your spreadsheet. BUT... have you considered `countif` (or even `countifs`) and/or `countblank`; perhaps in conjunction with an IF statement.

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz! I found a work around. Up to 50 intermediary empty cells. It works but with a monster formula. Do you see any better way to do it with a single formula? Thanks a lot! Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you can do it a bit more elegantly using a reverse lookup. The idea is to sort the data on descending order of row number, then use a match with -1 as the last parameter, which is equivalent to searching from the end of the data for the next non-blank.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(A2:A="","",rows(A2:A)+2-match(row(A2:A)+1,
query(SORT({IF(A2:A<>"",row(A2:A),""),row(A2:A)},2,false),"select Col1"),-1)-row(A2:A)),1))
```

[image]

If you wanted to keep it simple and just use a pull-down formula, an ordinary match is enough:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(A2="","",match(true,A3:A<>"",0)),1))
```

(it still has to be entered as an array formula because A3:A<>"" is an array of True and False)

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks a lot for that. I'm beginning to understand the use of Arrays and see their application. I ended up simplifing my monster formula into a shorter one but still big (reasoning explained below). Thanks for the explanation, I'll study the formulas and see how they can be used for further application. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a Monster formula but with simple iterative logics, and up to 50 intermediary blanks (for more only need to make the formula larger).

What I was lookind for was simply to print the cells/rows count of intermediary empty cells between 2 non-empty cells + adding to the count either the 1st non-empty cell or the last non-empty cell.

So for example if cell A1 and cell A9 have 8 empty cells between them, then return 8+1 (or 10-1).

The logics used is simple: 
probe how many possible empty cells there can be between each 2 non-empty cells counting the 1st non-empty as well within column A (in the formula below the possibility is up to 50 empty cells), and for each case return the intermediary rows -1 (the last row).

The formula:

```
=IFS(AND(A1="",A2=""),"",AND(A1="",A2<>""),"",AND(A1<>"",A2<>""),ROWS(A1),AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3<>""),ROWS(A1:A3)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4<>""),ROWS(A1:A4)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5<>""),ROWS(A1:A5)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6<>""),ROWS(A1:A6)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7<>""),ROWS(A1:A7)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8<>""),ROWS(A1:A8)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9<>""),ROWS(A1:A9)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10<>""),ROWS(A1:A10)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11<>""),ROWS(A1:A11)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12<>""),ROWS(A1:A12)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13<>""),ROWS(A1:A13)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14<>""),ROWS(A1:A14)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15<>""),ROWS(A1:A15)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16<>""),ROWS(A1:A16)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17<>""),ROWS(A1:A17)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18<>""),ROWS(A1:A18)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19<>""),ROWS(A1:A19)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20<>""),ROWS(A1:A20)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21<>""),ROWS(A1:A21)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22<>""),ROWS(A1:A22)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23<>""),ROWS(A1:A23)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24<>""),ROWS(A1:A24)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25<>""),ROWS(A1:A25)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26<>""),ROWS(A1:A26)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27<>""),ROWS(A1:A27)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28<>""),ROWS(A1:A28)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29<>""),ROWS(A1:A29)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30<>""),ROWS(A1:A30)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31<>""),ROWS(A1:A31)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32<>""),ROWS(A1:A32)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33<>""),ROWS(A1:A33)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34<>""),ROWS(A1:A34)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35<>""),ROWS(A1:A35)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36<>""),ROWS(A1:A36)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37<>""),ROWS(A1:A37)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38<>""),ROWS(A1:A38)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39<>""),ROWS(A1:A39)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40<>""),ROWS(A1:A40)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41<>""),ROWS(A1:A41)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42<>""),ROWS(A1:A42)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43<>""),ROWS(A1:A43)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44<>""),ROWS(A1:A44)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44="",A45<>""),ROWS(A1:A45)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44="",A45="",A46<>""),ROWS(A1:A46)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44="",A45="",A46="",A47<>""),ROWS(A1:A47)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44="",A45="",A46="",A47="",A48<>""),ROWS(A1:A48)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44="",A45="",A46="",A47="",A48="",A49<>""),ROWS(A1:A49)-1,AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4="",A5="",A6="",A7="",A8="",A9="",A10="",A11="",A12="",A13="",A14="",A15="",A16="",A17="",A18="",A19="",A20="",A21="",A22="",A23="",A24="",A25="",A26="",A27="",A28="",A29="",A30="",A31="",A32="",A33="",A34="",A35="",A36="",A37="",A38="",A39="",A40="",A41="",A42="",A43="",A44="",A45="",A46="",A47="",A48="",A49="",A50<>""),ROWS(A1:A50)-1)
```

Here the images sheet of the result:

[image]

[image]

[The Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3uN8mREbHmH-m_GxkNDhe8_LJSRRJ574ZkFoNS4Cbg/edit#gid=0)

Can it be done in a simpler way but still with a single formula?

Thanks a lot for your next input!

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I did some simplification of my previous Monster formula and learned the ArrayFormula application in the process.

1st I tried to shorten the big blank cells intervals into ranges formulations to see if it still worked.

For example I changed:

```
AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3="",A4<>""),ROWS(A1:A4)-1,
```

into

```
AND(A1<>"",A2:A3="",A4<>""),ROWS(A1:A4)-1,
```

And it shortened my formula from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

But then when pasting the new formula I got a #VALUE! error  'an array value could not be found'.

After further tests, I used the ArrayFormula and it worked by adapting the simple 'ranges' previously used to Arrays:

from this

```
AND(A1<>"",A2:A3="",A4<>""),ROWS(A1:A4)-1,
```

into this

```
AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A3=""),A4<>""),ROWS(A1:A4)-1,
```

With this final result:

```
=IFS(AND(A1="",A2=""),"",AND(A1="",A2<>""),"",AND(A1<>"",A2<>""),ROWS(A1),AND(A1<>"",A2="",A3<>""),ROWS(A1:A3)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A3=""),A4<>""),ROWS(A1:A4)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A4=""),A5<>""),ROWS(A1:A5)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A5=""),A6<>""),ROWS(A1:A6)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A6=""),A7<>""),ROWS(A1:A7)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A7=""),A8<>""),ROWS(A1:A8)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A8=""),A9<>""),ROWS(A1:A9)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A9=""),A10<>""),ROWS(A1:A10)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A10=""),A11<>""),ROWS(A1:A11)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A11=""),A12<>""),ROWS(A1:A12)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A12=""),A13<>""),ROWS(A1:A13)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A13=""),A14<>""),ROWS(A1:A14)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A14=""),A15<>""),ROWS(A1:A15)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A15=""),A16<>""),ROWS(A1:A16)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A16=""),A17<>""),ROWS(A1:A17)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A17=""),A18<>""),ROWS(A1:A18)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A18=""),A19<>""),ROWS(A1:A19)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A19=""),A20<>""),ROWS(A1:A20)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A20=""),A21<>""),ROWS(A1:A21)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A21=""),A22<>""),ROWS(A1:A22)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A22=""),A23<>""),ROWS(A1:A23)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A23=""),A24<>""),ROWS(A1:A24)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A24=""),A25<>""),ROWS(A1:A25)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A25=""),A26<>""),ROWS(A1:A26)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A26=""),A27<>""),ROWS(A1:A27)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A27=""),A28<>""),ROWS(A1:A28)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A28=""),A29<>""),ROWS(A1:A29)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A29=""),A30<>""),ROWS(A1:A30)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A30=""),A31<>""),ROWS(A1:A31)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A31=""),A32<>""),ROWS(A1:A32)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A32=""),A33<>""),ROWS(A1:A33)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A33=""),A34<>""),ROWS(A1:A34)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A34=""),A35<>""),ROWS(A1:A35)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A35=""),A36<>""),ROWS(A1:A36)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A36=""),A37<>""),ROWS(A1:A37)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A37=""),A38<>""),ROWS(A1:A38)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A38=""),A39<>""),ROWS(A1:A39)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A39=""),A40<>""),ROWS(A1:A40)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A40=""),A41<>""),ROWS(A1:A41)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A41=""),A42<>""),ROWS(A1:A42)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A42=""),A43<>""),ROWS(A1:A43)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A43=""),A44<>""),ROWS(A1:A44)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A44=""),A45<>""),ROWS(A1:A45)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A45=""),A46<>""),ROWS(A1:A46)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A46=""),A47<>""),ROWS(A1:A47)-1,AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A47=""),A48<>""),ROWS(A1:A48)-1, AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A48=""),A49<>""),ROWS(A1:A49)-1, AND(A1<>"",ArrayFormula(A2:A49=""),A50<>""),ROWS(A1:A50)-1)
```

[image]

[New Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3uN8mREbHmH-m_GxkNDhe8_LJSRRJ574ZkFoNS4Cbg/edit#gid=1012651717)