# How to return the rows/cells counts between groups of 2 cells with specific character separated by empty or non-empty cells in an adjacent column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I had a similar [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340737/how-to-count-rows-between-2-non-empty-cells-with-their-intermediary-empty-cells/56347094#56347094) but I'm not able to adapt the given solution to this case as an `ArrayFormula` or ideally a `Query` Formula.

I did not find a suitable duplicate question or solution.

I need to output the counts of cells as this sample (in column "Item 2"):

| Item 1 | Item 2 |
| --- | --- |
|  | 3 |
|  |  |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |
|  |  |
|  | 5 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  | 3 |
|  |  |
|  | 3 |
|  |  |
|  | 2 |

The counting method must be as counting each cell between 2 cells containing a clover emoji, those cells included.

An annoted screenshot with respective clover groups rectangles if that helps:

[image: clover groups]

I tried adapting the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56347312/10789707) answer but though it seems to work I'm not sure how to make it a fully fledged `ArrayFormula` formula or adapt it as a `Query` Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(A2="","",match(true,A3:A<>"",0)+1),1))
```

Gives this output:

[image: modifed solution]

I was not successful at attempting to adapt the [ArrayFormula solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56347312/10789707).

I would be very interested to learn about a solution to this problem using a `Query` formula if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=map(A:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ<>"",,ifna(xmatch("",offset(Σ,1,,rows(A:A)))+1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockingfreakshow that works great as `ArrayFormula`. Thanks for the alternative. I'll need to study it break it down asap. Be well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution

```
=IFNA(MAP(A:A,LAMBDA(_,LET(o,OFFSET(_,1,,9^9),ROWS(_:XLOOKUP(_,o,o))))))
```

Comment: Thanks @z" for the alternative. I tested but it does not seem to give the expected output. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/SMk6sTa.png

Comment: The cells between the emojis are not really blank. They probably contain an empty string `""`. If you fix that the formula should work.

Comment: That was the cause. Thanks again! Be well!